# How can I create a one time cron schedule that would execute only once in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, cron, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

I have used cron schedule in C# to create an application that should trigger a job only once. This code piece is throwing an exception,
An unhandled exception of type 'Quartz.SchedulerException' occurred in Quartz.dll

Below is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test();
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        IScheduler scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();

        IJobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.Create<SatellitePaymentGenerationJob>()
            .WithIdentity("TestJob")
            .Build();
        Console.WriteLine(DateBuilder.DateOf(16, 30, 00, 24, 2, 2015));
        //ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        //    .ForJob(jobDetail)
        //    .WithCronSchedule("0 0 12 20 4 ? *")
        //    .WithIdentity("TestTrigger")
        //    .StartNow()
        //    .Build();
        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                             .WithDescription("Once")
                             .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.RepeatForever().WithRepeatCount(1))
                             .StartAt(DateBuilder.DateOf(12, 43, 00, 26, 2, 2015))
                             .Build();

        scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
        scheduler.Start();
    }
}

internal class SatellitePaymentGenerationJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("test");
    }
}
```

I believe that the way I have done scheduling to be execute only once is causing the issue. Please advice.

Comment: you need a cronschedule still

Answer (score 0):

```
  ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                               .WithDescription("Once")
                               .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                               .WithIntervalInSeconds(40)
                               .RepeatForever())
                               .StartAt(DateBuilder.DateOf(14, 41, 00, 26, 2, 2015))
                               .EndAt(DateBuilder.DateOf(15, 14, 20))
                               .Build();
```